# Setting up room in oTree

Tags: otree

I have a quick question about Rooms in oTree. I have only one room in settings.py. Do I need to create separate rooms for separate treatments? Because when I deploy the experiment in oTree hub, it takes me to the treatments and after I choose the relevant treatment, I just go to the same room for all the treatments. So what I have done is have just one room for the entire experiment and then via oTree Hub create separate sessions. And use session codes in otree hr. Do you think my method is alright? I am new to oTree and plan to run my experiment soon, so I don't want to make too many changes if my method is correct. The codes I use for setting room is below:

```py
ROOMS = [
    dict(
        name='our_study',
        display_name='Decision making'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need different rooms for different treatments, best you assign treatments through session.

Comment: Your answer is a bit thin without a why.  Readers want to be convinced that its the right answer, just by reading it.

Comment: @Papayapap Thank you so much for your advice. I was really confused and I found your answer so helpful.